# Showing as set of vectors are/are not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I started reading up on linear algebra (I took matrix a few years back), and I found this problem.

Consider a vector space $V$ where $V=U\bigoplus W$ for subspaces $U$ and $W$, and $u_{1},...,u_{n}$ a linearly independent list of vectors from $U$. Prove or disprove that for any non-zero vector $w\in W$, $u_{1},...,u_{n},w$ is a linearly independent list.

My reasoning is that, since $U\bigoplus W$ is a direct sum, the intersection of $U$ and $W$ is trivial; thus $w\in W$ must be linearly independent to any vector, specifically $u_{1},...,u_{n}$, in $U$. Would this be correct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. More precisely, we might say that if there is a linear combination 
$$ aw+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i=0$$
with $a\ne 0$, then rearranging, we get 
$$ w=-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{a}\cdot u_i$$
so that $w\in U$. This implies that $w\in U\cap W$, and hence that $w=0$. So, if we know $w\ne 0$, this is impossible.